# No music quality option in Clubhouse for Android

Tags: applications

I know the Clubhouse have the music playing feature in the new version of it, but I don't have the music quality option in my Clubhouse app. Based of [this post](https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/social/clubhouse-how-to-turn-on-and-use-the-new-music-mode-feature-7575733/lite/), it must have the below icons:

> #### How to enable and use Music Mode in Clubhouse?
>
> To enable the new feature, users can open Clubhouse and once they are in a room, they can navigate to the options by tapping on the three-dot menu on the top-right. Look for the 'Audio Quality' option here and subsequently, Choose 'Music' amongst the various options.

[image]

But my room options are like below:

[image]

My phone is Xiaomi Note 9A on Android 10, as you can see below:

[image]

And its permission are :

[image]

Also I use dual app option in my Xiaomi phone, so I have two Clubhouse app at my cellphone.

So if possible, I want to know why I don't have music options in my Clubhouse rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the article and [Clubhouse blog article](https://blog.clubhouse.com/music-mode-hallway-search/), the Music Mode is currently only available on iOS.

> As was the case with spatial audio, Music Mode will roll out on iOS first with Android as a fast follow.

This is strengthen with the remark on [Clubhouse Knowledge Center](https://clubhouseapp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408617060243-What-is-music-mode-).

> #### What is music mode?
>
> ***Note:** Music mode is currently only available on iOS.*